# Disable Command-W in the terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard

Is there any way to disable <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in the terminal?

On several occasions I have accidentally closed a terminal window containing important information when I meant to close a Safari tab and did not realize that the terminal was the active window.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To disable <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> in Terminal, do the following:

- From the  menu in the top left corner of the screen, select **System Preferences**. Click on **Keyboard** then **Keyboard Shortcuts** then **Application Shortcuts**.
  [image]
- Click the + button to add a new shortcut
- Select "Terminal.app" for the application, and for the command, type `Close` (this is case sensitive). You must provide a keybinding, but it doesn't have to be the default. In the shortcut box, give it a **different shortcut**, like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> [image]
- Now <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> will not close your terminal windows.

Comment: I mis-spoke in my question. I actually meant to prevent closing a tab, but your answer still works well with the slight change of "Close Window" to "Close Tab". BTW, thanks for the **VERY** complete answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Nice screenshots! May I ask which program you used to take them? Or did you change your desktop background to all-white?

Comment: The program is called "Mac OS X" :-) Command-shift-4, spacebar, click in the window.

Comment: Command-ctrl-shift-4, spacebar puts the screenshots in your clipboard so you can paste them.

Comment: It is so bizzare that company that prides itself on UX has concluded _"if people want to unbind this, they must instead bind it something ELSE."_ Just what I want to do, think about what keybinding I'm not using anywhere when they're all muscle memory.

Answer (score 35):

You can set a prompt before closing in the preferences:

**Terminal Preferences → Settings → Shell**

[image]

Comment: Answers crossed paths. This is a good one too.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for this particular use case. Disabling standard shortcuts makes me feel icky and would get frustrating when muscle-memory kicks in when I *want* to close a terminal tab/window.

Comment: -1: OP asked a very specific question that could easily be modified for various applications. This is a Terminal.app specific answer which does not answer the question.

Comment: For those using iTerm go to Prefrerences -> Profiles -> Session -> Prompt before closing! Make sure you are on the correct profile (your default one has the star!) http://images.luo.ma/osx/iterm/preferences-session-always-prompt-before-closing.jpg

Answer (score 20):

I tried all of the above, and none worked for me.

What worked was changing the shortcut for the **"Close"** command.

[image]

Comment: Same here. "Close" worked for me but "Close Windows" did not.

Comment: Ian, it says "iterm" not "TERMINAL"

Comment: @LM126, yep, my example is using iTerm2, so not sure what your on about?

Comment: you can make iterm prompt when you close a session. iterm pref -> profiles -> session: always prompt before closing. this will prevent you from accidentally close session by shot cut.

Comment: This worked for me on Mojave 10.14.5 - Since the original answer is from 2012, this answer is now more correct.

Comment: This work for me on Catalina 10.15.4.

Answer (score 10):

I propose this:

In iTerm: Open Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), click tab `Keys`, at the bottom of `Key Bindings` click `+`. In the appearing dialog, click `Click to Set`, then type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and leave the default Action `Ignore`.

- no need to manipulate global settings
- no need to confirm conscious closing

Comment: This is the only effective solution for me on Mac OS 10.10

Comment: Do you know how to add an alternative shortcut to close the window/tab then?

Comment: How about using Ctrl-D?

Answer (score 5):

A bit of an old question but in iTerm2 this helped me:

**iTerm2** → **Preferences** → **keys** → Add key mapping: "command + w" => ignore

Comment: Better than ignoring the useful command, you can undo the closing of the tab with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Keyboard System Preferences and select "Keyboard Shortcuts". Then choose *Application Shortcuts* from the left and click *+*. Choose "Terminal.app" and enter a menu item that is not that critical. I chose "Bring All to Front". Then click into *Keyboard Shortcut* and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Click *OK*.

Using this technique have have successfully redirected the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

For iterm, as @Shwaydogg mention:

> For those using iTerm go to Prefrerences -> Profiles -> Session -> Prompt before closing!

Comment: That actually is THE answer to this post. No using the OS to hack-opt-out of the shortcut. Not ignoring the key in iTerm. Simply confirming that the user truly wants to close this. Of course, if your need is to totally disable it, the "Ignore" options is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth mentioning BetterTouchTool (http://www.bettertouchtool.net/)

I wanted to have both <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>  & <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> both perform `Copy` (muscle memory, don't ask).  The native method only allows you one key per command, with BTT I was able to have both keys mapped to same command, while also avoid the undesired Close WIndow behaviour