# Remove keybinding in a specific app (X11)

Tags: macos, keyboard, x11

Mac OS' `X11.app` uses certain key bindings that I'd rather send to the underlying X app in use. Specifically I'd like to pass `Command+W` and `Command-1` (and `-2`, etc) to the X app in question.

Is there any way to disable keybindings in an app? I'm aware of the system dialog that allows adding additional keybindings, but that doesn't seem to allow removing them.

Or maybe there's a way that's specific to `X11.app`?

Comment: Rather than remove key-bindings in keyboard prefs, which you cannot do directly, I change ones I want rid of to things like cmd/opt/ctrl/shift/F19 - so I'll never trigger them, then add the now freed-up key command to wherever I actually wanted it.

Comment: Have a look there: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44412/disable-command-w-in-the-terminal